# Customize React-Calendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I want to use react-calendar in two components in my app.

```
import Calendar from "react-calendar";
```

I customized it. Everything is ok. When I want to use in different component with different customization, it effected first component. How can I customize two different react-calendar?

Comment: How did you customize it ? did you use the props that the library offers ? or did you change the code in the node module folder ?

Comment: I copied codes from node module folder. And I changed it.  ClassNames I could not change.